# Multiple criteria for same column

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a column which has same value but other columns differ. I want to write search for this condition. How do i do this ? I am getting duplicate criteria exception.

```
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(src)){                           
criteria.createCriteria("params").add(Restrictions.eq("tagName",   
OptionalParams.TagName.SOURCE)).add(Restrictions.ilike("name", "Version")).add(Restrictions.ilike("value", src,MatchMode.START));
}

if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(tgt)){
                criteria.createCriteria("params").add(Restrictions.eq("tagName", OptionalParams.TagName.TARGET))
                .add(Restrictions.ilike("name", "Version")).add(Restrictions.ilike("value", tgt,MatchMode.START));
            }

  57273 Version 0       1.2.0   9dbb
  57275 Version 1       1.2.3   9dbb
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post what have you tried! the query for example

Comment: update in your question, here is unreadeable

Comment: i've update the question... please have a look

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("params");
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(src)){                           
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tagName",   
    OptionalParams.TagName.SOURCE)).add(Restrictions.ilike("name", "Version")).add(Restrictions.ilike("value", src,MatchMode.START));
    }

    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(tgt)){
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tagName", OptionalParams.TagName.TARGET))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("name", "Version")).add(Restrictions.ilike("value", tgt,MatchMode.START));
                }
```

You were getting the exception because, you were writing criteria twice in a same transaction on same object. Also, `createCriteria(*.class)` should have parameter as class.

For more details please have a look at the http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html